# Problem pdf preview LyX in mac OS 10.15

Tags: lyx

I have just downloaded MacTeX and LyX. Problem: the view button is shaded and disabled... I can't generate a pdf preview of the file or export it!
Do you have a solution to this problem?
Thank you very much !!

Comment: Try Tools > Reconfigure and restart LyX, specially if you installed LyX first.

Comment: Thanks Fran !! It worked !!  Have a nice day